# Property 'toGMTString' does not exist on type 'Date'

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use date function on Typescript:

```
let date = new Date();
let gmt = date.toGMTString();
```

Now error I got is:

```
Property 'toGMTString' does not exist on type 'Date'
```

So how to convert local date to GMT using typescript?

Other methods are working fine like `getTime()`, `getDate()`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
let gmt = date['toGMTString']();
```

Answer (score 27):

`toGMTString()` is deprecated, that's why it is not included in `Date` typings. You can use **`toUTCString()`** instead.